# Sending intent to another app in Android Emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I want to experiment with sending data to other apps using the Eclipse Emulator but it doesn't seem to find any apps that support the ACTION_SEND intent, so I'm assuming there's some issue with doing this via emulator. I can't find any information on how to get this working, is it possible or will I need an actual android phone to do this?

code

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message); 
        String message = editText.getText().toString(); 
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: use content providers

Answer (score 1):

Android Emulator is made to work like a physical device. Also it already includes Messages and Email app which can receive this intent.

Check http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html for further information.

Answer (score 0):

> but it doesn't seem to find any apps that support the ACTION_SEND intent

Partly, that is because your `Intent` is missing the MIME type.

Once you fix that, there still may not be anything on the emulator that supports whatever MIME type you chose. An emulator does not have that many apps. You are welcome to write your own app that handles `ACTION_SEND` requests for your desired MIME type, to serve as a testbed.